# Why Does this code not compile when the compiler creates the exact same type of instruction from the c++ code

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly

Consider the following code

```
int a = 10;
int b = 2;
int c = 0;

int asmdivide(void);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

     c = a / b;
    asmdivide();
    return 0;
}

int asmdivide()
{
    __asm

    {
        push dword ptr[a]
        push dword ptr[b]
        pop ecx
        idiv ecx, dword ptr[a] //causes compile error
        push ecx
        pop dword ptr[c]
    }
    return c;
}
```

why does this line `idiv ecx, ds:dword ptr[a] //causes compile error` Cause a compile error when the compiler generates this instruction `idiv eax,dword ptr ds:[1308004h]`from this line  `int b = 2;

The error outputted is

```
error C2414: illegal number of operands
```

Please see the screenshot below for assembly output

[image: Assembly Output]

I am using Visual Studio 2013. 
Any explanation would be valued

Comment: Still does not compile with the same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might seem like your code and the disassembly are the same, but that's just due to how the debugger chooses to display the disassembly.

The dividend for `IDIV` is implicit, and is always `EAX` when dividing by a 32-bit value (actually `EDX:EAX`). To quote Intel's manual:

```
F7 /7    IDIV r/m32   M   Valid   Valid   Signed divide EDX:EAX by r/m32, with result
                                          stored in EAX ←Quotient, EDX ←Remainder.
```

So your attempt to specify a different register as the dividend will fail.

You can only specify the divisor for `IDIV`, as in:

```
cdq                 ; sign-extend eax into edx:eax
idiv dword ptr [a]  ; divide edx:eax by [a]
```

Comment: So what is the correct way to write this instruction

Comment: To specify only a single operand (which will be the divisor). I've added an example.

Comment: Thanks that works as I expected now, Do you know why it was made this way

Comment: I don't really know Intel's reason for making `IDIV` work this way. It's just always been that way on the x86.